# Install npm sqlite3 on Windows for Electron App

Tags: node.js, npm, sqlite, electron, node-gyp

I have a problem installing sqlite3 with npm in windows for an electron app.
I installed sqlite3 with npm:

```
npm i sqlite3
```

Then I executed:

```
.\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd
```

And I have this error:

```
× Rebuild Failed

An unhandled error occurred inside electron-rebuild
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@8.12.0 | win32 | x64
gyp http GET https://atom.io/download/electron/v2.0.10/iojs-v2.0.10.tar.gz
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN atom.io:443
gyp ERR! stack     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:67:26)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\WindowsDev\\CopyWatcher\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--target=2.0.10" "--arch=x64" "--dist-url=https://atom.io/download/electron" "--build-from-source" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=D:\\WindowsDev\\CopyWatcher\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\electron-v2.0-win32-x64" "--host=https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com" "--remote_path=./{name}/v4.0.2/{toolset}/" "--package_name=electron-v2.0-win32-x64.tar.gz"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\WindowsDev\CopyWatcher\node_modules\sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v8.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Everything seems to indicate that it is the proxy, I have it configured well in .npmrc, but it does not work in this case, so I try to execute the command that launches electron-rebuild with the option --proxy:

```
"C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\WindowsDev\\CopyWatcher\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--target=2.0.10" "--arch=x64" "--dist-url=https://atom.io/download/electron" "--build-from-source" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=D:\\WindowsDev\\CopyWatcher\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\electron-v2.0-win32-x64" "--proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3131/" "--host=https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com" "--remote_path=./{name}/v4.0.2/{toolset}/" "--package_name=electron-v2.0-win32-x64.tar.gz"
```

But then I have this error:

```
gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: D:\WindowsDev\CopyWatcher) while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (D:\WindowsDev\CopyWatcher\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:345:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\WindowsDev\\CopyWatcher\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--target=2.0.10" "--arch=x64" "--dist-url=https://atom.io/download/electron" "--build-from-source" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=D:\\\\WindowsDev\\\\CopyWatcher\\\\node_modules\\\\sqlite3\\\\lib\\\\binding\\\\electron-v2.0-win32-x64" "--proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3131/" "--host=https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com" "--remote_path=./{name}/v4.0.2/{toolset}/" "--package_name=electron-v2.0-win32-x64.tar.gz"
```

It seems that it looks for a file named "binding.gyp" but it is not and I do not know where it should be or what it must have to work.

Some help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, here are the steps that make it work:

First remove your node_modules folder and package-lock.json
and follow below steps

install electron-rebuild

> npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild

install sqlite3 using npm

> npm install --save sqlite3

rebuild electron with sqlite3. In package.json scripts section, add:

> "rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3"

run the following command

> npm run rebuild

Now, you’ll get another binding, something like:

> /.../node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/electron-v1.4-darwin-x64/node_sqlite3.node

which is accepted by electron.

Comment: Thanks this solve this specific problem, but i get other now. I'm going to write another question.